# conda search --subdir

Tags: anaconda, conda

Здраствуйте,

в документации conda написано

> **--subdir, --platform
> Поиск заданного подкаталога . Должен быть отформатирован как «osx-64», «linux-32», «win-64» и т. д. По умолчанию выполняется поиск на текущей платформе**

Но где взять полный списсок --subdir? Если у кого есть просьба выложить. Зарание спасибо даже за прочтение вопроса.